# On the Lebesgue outer measure of union of a measurable and non-measurable set

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

Let $A, B\subset \mathbb{R}$ be two sets such that $A$ is Lebesgue measurable and $B$ is not Lebesgue measurable.
Let $m^*$ denote the Lebesgue outer measure on $\mathbb{R}$.

I know that $m^*(A\cup B)=m^*(A)+m^*(B)$ whenever $A\cap B=\emptyset$ (that is, the intersection of $A$ and $B$ is empty).

But if we have $A\cap B\neq\emptyset$, is it true that $m^*(A\cup B)=m^*(A)+m^*(B)-m^*(A\cap B)$?

I think that this is not true, but I could not find a counterexample.
What would be a counterexample, if any?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true. You need Caratheodory's criterion: Since $A$ is measurable it satisfies for any set $S\subset\mathbb{R}$
$$m^*(S)=m^*(S\setminus A)+m^*(S\cap A).$$
If you put $S=B$ and $S=A\cup B$ you obtain two equations:
$$m^*(B)=m^*(B\setminus A)+m^*(B\cap A)$$
$$m^*(A\cup B)=m^*((A\cup B)\setminus A)+m^*((A\cup B)\cap A)=m^*(B\setminus A)+m^*(A).$$
If you add these two you obtain
$$m^*(A\cup B) +m^*(B\setminus A)+m^*(B\cap A)=m^*(B)+m^*(B\setminus A)+m^*(A),$$
which is our conjecture.